# Get range from Hash entries

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash:

```
{
  "01/01"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "01/05"=>{:a=>1, :b=>0},
  "31/08"=>{:a=>26, :b=>32},
  "01/09"=>{:a=>2, :b=>9},
  "02/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>3},
  "04/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>4},
  "06/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>26},
  "07/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "06/10"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1},
  "07/11"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1}
}
```

That hash has 10 entries but I need to display only 7.
How can I get only 7 entries to use the values ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for only the values (in, say, an array) or do you need a hash with only 7 key/value pairs?

Comment: `hash.first(7).to_h`. Quite semantic.

Comment: Last seven pairs `hash.to_a.last(7).to_h` or `hash.to_a[-7..-1].to_h`.

Comment: Please, update your question with the required output. Better all requirements to be in the question than around in comments. This lets people help you better. :) Anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: you have three decent answers here .. time to accept one

Answer (score 1):

**First 7 Elements**

You can use `Array#slice` on the hash converted to an array, then convert back to a hash. Here's an example:

```
x = {
  "01/01"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "01/05"=>{:a=>1, :b=>0},
  "31/08"=>{:a=>26, :b=>32},
  "01/09"=>{:a=>2, :b=>9},
  "02/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>3},
  "04/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>4},
  "06/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>26},
  "07/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "06/10"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1},
  "07/11"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1}
}

y = x.to_a.slice(0,7).to_h
```

Then `y` is

```
{
  "01/01"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "01/05"=>{:a=>1, :b=>0},
  "31/08"=>{:a=>26, :b=>32},
  "01/09"=>{:a=>2, :b=>9},
  "02/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>3},
  "04/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>4},
  "06/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>26}
}
```

Hash also has a slice method (at least in 2.5.1), but it needs to given the keys to slice from the hash. If you knew the keys in advance, you could do:

```
y = x.slice("01/01", "01/05", "31/08", "01/09", "02/09", "04/09", "06/09")
```

With the same result for `y`.

`Hash#slice` docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice

**Last 7 Elements**

You can use `Array#last` on the hash converted to an array, then convert back to a hash. Here's an example:

```
x = {
  "01/01"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "01/05"=>{:a=>1, :b=>0},
  "31/08"=>{:a=>26, :b=>32},
  "01/09"=>{:a=>2, :b=>9},
  "02/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>3},
  "04/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>4},
  "06/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>26},
  "07/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "06/10"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1},
  "07/11"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1}
}

y = x.to_a.last(7).to_h
```

Then `y` is

```
{
  "01/09"=>{:a=>2, :b=>9},
  "02/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>3},
  "04/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>4},
  "06/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>26},
  "07/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "06/10"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1},
  "07/11"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1}
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I need the last seven. from the end to start (DESC)

Comment: @StackOverflow made an edit, the second part shows how to get the last 7 elements

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear, but maybe this can help.

To get the first seven [values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
h.values.first(7) # or h.values.take(7)
# => [{:a=>0, :b=>2}, {:a=>1, :b=>0}, {:a=>26, :b=>32}, {:a=>2, :b=>9}, {:a=>0, :b=>3}, {:a=>0, :b=>4}, {:a=>0, :b=>26}]
```

To get the first seven [keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-keys):

```
h.keys.first(7) # => ["01/01", "01/05", "31/08", "01/09", "02/09", "04/09", "06/09"]
```

Or to get just the [first](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) seven elements, as already pointed in a comment:

```
h.first(7).to_h
# {"01/01"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2}, "01/05"=>{:a=>1, :b=>0}, "31/08"=>{:a=>26, :b=>32}, "01/09"=>{:a=>2, :b=>9}, "02/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>3}, "04/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>4}, "06/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>26}}
```

**Edit:** to get last seven from end to start

```
h.values.last(7).reverse # => [{:a=>0, :b=>1}, {:a=>0, :b=>1}, {:a=>0, :b=>2}, {:a=>0, :b=>26}, {:a=>0, :b=>4}, {:a=>0, :b=>3}, {:a=>2, :b=>9}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) with a counter.

```
h = {
  "01/01"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "01/05"=>{:a=>1, :b=>0},
  "31/08"=>{:a=>26, :b=>32},
  "01/09"=>{:a=>2, :b=>9},
  "02/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>3},
  "04/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>4},
  "06/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>26},
  "07/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  "06/10"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1},
  "07/11"=>{:a=>0, :b=>1}
}

n = 7
h.select { (n-=1) >= 0 }
  #=> {"01/01"=>{:a=>0, :b=>2},
  #    "01/05"=>{:a=>1, :b=>0},
  #    "31/08"=>{:a=>26, :b=>32},
  #    "01/09"=>{:a=>2, :b=>9},
  #    "02/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>3},
  #    "04/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>4},
  #    "06/09"=>{:a=>0, :b=>26}}
```